# Feign Client making Post call instead of GET

Tags: spring, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign

We are using netflix gateway API, Zuul and Feign client.
We make a call to our security-api for each request for user authentication check.
While communicating with remote rest client (micro service for validating token) seeing unexpected exception.

```
Caused by: feign.FeignException: status 405 reading RemoteSecurityAPI#validateToken(String); content:
{"timestamp":1508809658401,"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException","message":"Request
method 'POST' not supported","path":"/api/v1//auth/validate/token"}
        at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:62) ~[feign-core-9.5.0.jar!/:na]

public class AuthenticationPreZuulFilter extends ZuulFilter
{
    @Autowired
    RemoteSecurityAPI securityAPI;
    final RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    final HttpServletRequest request = requestContext.getRequest();
    final String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    String authToken = header.substring(7);
    securityAPI.validateToken(authToken);
}

@FeignClient(name = "martmonkey-security-api")
public interface RemoteSecurityAPI
{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "${jwt.route.authentication.validate}")
    public void validateToken(@Param("authToken") String authToken);
}
```

jwt.route.authentication.validate=/api/v1//auth/validate/token?token={authToken}

```
zuul:
  #Service will be mapped under the /api URI
  prefix: /api/v1
  strip-prefix: false
  sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization
  routes:
    martmonkey-security-api:
      path: /auth/**
      strip-prefix: false
      sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization
      serviceId: martmonkey-security-api
    martmonkey-user-api:
      path: /users/**
      serviceId: martmonkey-user-api
```

jwt.route.authentication.validate=/auth/validate/token

```
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@Api(value="Security check.", description="Operations pertaining to login.")
public class AuthenticationResource
{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "${jwt.route.authentication.validate}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> validateToken(@QueryParam("token") final String authToken)
    {
    }
}
```

Why gateway api is making a request with method type 'post' though we have said to use "method = RequestMethod.GET".

Comment: Like to mention earlier our API was using POST we changed it to GET for some reason. After this change we have build, deploy and start api. Request to gateway is "http://localhost:8007/api/v1/users/badce5d53eac41d1879cec20bc9ef21b" method type GET. So it first hit to Zuul filter then we ask remote api to validate token coming as part of header "Authorization Bearer ${some_token}".